# JSQMessagesViewController: How to get senderId in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a function for avatars that's called in `viewDidLoad` (this is the function if it helps although I think the problem is not the function itself: https://pastebin.com/ksHmucTX).

In `viewDidLoad` I call it:

```
createAvatar(senderId: self.senderId, senderDisplayName: self.senderDisplayName, user: self.currentUser!,  color: UIColor.lightGray)
```

But since I am only passing in my information (as the current user), when using the app I only see my avatar and not the avatars of everyone else in the chat.

In the `avatarImageDataForItemAt` function, there is an index path to figure out which message is which:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {

let message = messages[indexPath.row]
return avatars[message.senderId]
}
```

So I'm wondering how to get the proper `senderId` (i.e. the ID of whoever sent a message) in viewDidLoad so I can plug it into the `createAvatars` call, as opposed to what I have now, where `senderId` is ONLY my ID - thus making everyone's avatar appear, and not only mine (or whoever is the current user).

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

```
func getParticipantInfo() {
    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomIdGlobal)
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for each in snapDict {
                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.createAvatar(senderId: uid, senderDisplayName: name, photoUrl: avatar,  color: UIColor.lightGray)
                    self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

createAvatar:

```
func createAvatar(senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String,  photoUrl: String, color: UIColor) {
    if self.avatars[senderId] == nil {
        let img = MyImageCache.sharedCache.object(forKey: senderId as AnyObject) as? UIImage
        if img != nil {
            self.avatars[senderId] = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: img, diameter: 30)
        } else if photoUrl != "" {
            // the images are very small, so the following methods work just fine, no need for Alamofire here
            if photoUrl.contains("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com") {
                self.storage.reference(forURL: photoUrl).data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        assertionFailure("Error with Firebase Storage")
                    }
                    else {
                        let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.avatars[senderId] = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: newImage, diameter: 30)

                        MyImageCache.sharedCache.setObject(newImage!, forKey: senderId as AnyObject, cost: data!.count)
                    }
                }
            } else if let data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string:photoUrl)! as URL) {
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)!
                self.avatars[senderId] = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: newImage, diameter: 30)
                MyImageCache.sharedCache.setObject(newImage, forKey: senderId as AnyObject, cost: data.length)
            } else {
                // Initials
                let senderName = nameDictionary.value(forKey: senderId) as! String
                let initials = senderName.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.characters.first!)") + "\($1.characters.first!)" }

                let placeholder = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(withUserInitials: initials, backgroundColor: UIColor.gray, textColor: UIColor.white, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))

                MyImageCache.sharedCache.setObject(placeholder!, forKey: senderId as AnyObject)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Initials
        let senderName = nameDictionary.value(forKey: senderId) as! String
        let initials = senderName.components(separatedBy: " ").reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.characters.first!)") + "\($1.characters.first!)" }

        let placeholder = JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(withUserInitials: initials, backgroundColor: UIColor.gray, textColor: UIColor.white, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), diameter: UInt(kJSQMessagesCollectionViewAvatarSizeDefault))

        MyImageCache.sharedCache.setObject(placeholder!, forKey: senderId as AnyObject)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the JSQMessage contains the senderId of the sender, so the function below already specifies what avatar to be returned:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,    avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource!    {
let message = messages[indexPath.row]
return avatars[message.senderId]
}
```

You will need to add an avatar to

```
var avatars = [String: JSQMessagesAvatarImage]()
```

I assume you have the userId of that user, so get the avatar the same way every time someone joins the conversation. Lets say userToChatWith:

```
    createAvatar(userToChatWith.userKey, senderDisplayName: userToChatWithName,  user: userToChatWith, color: UIColor.lightGray)
```

Comment: Each user in the app has a unique ID. But I think where I'm getting confused is in how to get, in your example, `userToChatWith` in viewDidLoad when I call `createAvatar`.

Comment: if each user has an "unique id" and you have that id in viewDidLoad, then for each id you call

Comment: createAvatar(uniqueId, senderDisplayName: nameOfThatUniqueId,  user: userToChatWith, color: UIColor.lightGray). I use a struct for users, but as you are working with currentUser, I presume you are doing the same? If your currentUser is in another format, put every user in that format. The idea is that you need the "unique id", username and the pictureURL to get the image of the server, so maybe change the "user: userToChatWith" to "imageUrl: pictureURL"?

Comment: I took your advice and changed the "user" parameter to "photoUrl" (String), and called `createAvatar` in the function where all chat participants' info is retrieved from Firebase and sorted into dictionaries in a for loop. Check my edit - it's unfortunately not working, but I'm so confused at this point I don't know why! With `createAvatar` in the loop, it should create an avatar for each user (UID) in the chat, right?

Comment: you still have to change the func createAvatar(senderId It is expecting a user and you are now send it a string (the URL). But then you set self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid),so a String for a key, where the avatars dict should be expecting a [String: JSQMessagesAvatarImage]. That is totally different. And why go around and around, you already have the pictureURL (in the form of let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String), why: self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid) and than in the self.createAvatar  self.avatarDictionary.value(forKey: uid) as! String ??

Comment: I did change the function, to `func createAvatar(senderId: String, senderDisplayName: String,  photoUrl: String, color: UIColor)`. And in that function I provide `self.avatarDictionary.value(forKey: uid)` because that dictionary is where each user's photoUrl is held. Sorry I'm still really confused - should I be going about this differently? I've changed the function to take a photoUrl string instead of a user, and I figured putting the `createAvatar` function call in the loop would create an avatar for all participants, then convert it to the proper format (JSQMessagesAvatarImage).

Comment: Personally I created a struct for my users, instead of dictionaries for the individual items, but if the rest works for you, fine.
But can't you just do: 
self.createAvatar(senderId: uid, senderDisplayName: name, photoUrl: avatar,  color: UIColor.lightGray)
and should you not turn these two around: 
                    self.createAvatar(senderId: uid, senderDisplayName: self.nameDictionary.value(forKey: uid) as! String, photoUrl: self.avatarDictionary.value(forKey: uid) as! String,  color: UIColor.lightGray)
                    self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadData()

Comment: I thinks there will be a race for what comes back first, so you might have a problem there. 
Also do you have to use DispatchQueue.main.async? I thought that Firebase took care of that aspect.

Comment: You're right, I changed the call to `self.createAvatar(senderId: uid, senderDisplayName: name, photoUrl: avatar,  color: UIColor.lightGray)`. You can disregard the nav bar, that's handled a bit differently. Anyway I tried changing the function call and even getting rid of the dispatch block but none of the avatars are showing up. Check my edit, I put what I currently have for the `createAvatar` function, and what I currently have in `getParticipantInfo`, which is where I call it. I'm still not understanding why it's not working though!

Comment: UPDATE: So, I was calling `getParticipantInfo` (where I moved the `createAvatar` call) in `viewDidAppear`. I moved it to `viewDidLoad` and all avatars are showing up. That creates a new set of problems unfortunately however unrelated to this issue - I'm gonna mark you answer as correct, thanks for getting me back on track!